NUCLEO F401RE and multiple reading with HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA
I'm doing a project involving STM32 and an accelerometer sensor (LIS2DE)
I have to read every second the register from the sensor and send it via UART to arduino IDE but, idk why, the other two HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA won't work
I tried to delete the first Mem_Read and only the second would work, so I checked the return value of the second call and it gives me HAL_BUSY.
Using HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA and HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_DMA works correctly, but I wanted to experiment this way because professors suggested us to use this function to do automatically Transmit+Receive.
Is better to use Transmit and Receive separately or this one in your opinion? And why?
Furthermore, is there a function to get all 3-axis value? I inspected the datasheet and I saw an auto increment feature, but I dind't find any example with that
I'll leave my code, obviously I set a timer of 1 second and I set up DMA for UART_TX, I2C_TX and I2C_RX, enabled interrupts from UART, TIM and I2C event
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim){
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_X_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)&acc[0], 1);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_Y_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)&acc[1], 1);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_Z_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)&acc[2], 1);
}

void HAL_I2C_MemRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
        if(count==2){    //because I'll receive a single interrupt for each Mem_Read, so after the third MemRxCpltCallback will transmit thanks UART values
        count = 0;

        len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "X: %+.3fg   Y: %+.3fg   Z: %+.3fg\n",
                acc[0] / 256.0 * 4.0,
                acc[1] / 256.0 * 4.0,
                acc[2] / 256.0 * 4.0);
        HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (unsigned char*)string, len);
         }
         else
                count++;
}

Thanks for any help, if you need more information or there is something not good in the question, tell me and I'll update the question. I can post a link for the zip file of my code too if someone needs it
--- UPDATE ---
Now I just start the first one with the TIM IT, then other ones are triggered by previous one and last one triggers the print, just using a global variable to keep track of which call is executed. Do you think it's a quite decent solution? It works but seems very dirty to me, but it's mandatory to use I2C with DMA
Btw thanks again for every contribution
    #if VERSION == 2
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim){
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_X_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)(acc+count), 1);
    count++;
}

void HAL_I2C_MemRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c){
    switch(count){
        case 1:
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_Y_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)(acc+count), 1);
            count++;
            break;
        case 2:
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, OUT_Z_ADD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)(acc+count), 1);
            count++;
            break;
        case 3:
            count=0;

            len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "X: %+.3fg   Y: %+.3fg   Z: %+.3fg, (Tot:%+.3fg | %+.3fm/s²)\n",
                    acc[0] / 256.0 * 4.0,
                    acc[1] / 256.0 * 4.0,
                    acc[2] / 256.0 * 4.0,
                    sqrt(pow(acc[0],2)+pow(acc[1],2)+pow(acc[2],2))/64.0,
                    sqrt(pow(acc[0],2)+pow(acc[1],2)+pow(acc[2],2))/64.0 * 9.80665);
            HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (unsigned char*)string, len);
    }
}
#endif

--- UPDATE2 ---
Here there is my main, other code is generated automatically plus the two callbacks that @pmacfarlane suggested
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, (uint8_t*)CTRL_REG1, sizeof(CTRL_REG1)) == HAL_OK)
      len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "LIS2DE found!\n");
  else{
      ACCEL_ADD = LIS2DE12_ADD;
      if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, (uint8_t*)CTRL_REG1, sizeof(CTRL_REG1)) == HAL_OK)
          len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "LIS2DE12 found!\n");
      else
          len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "Accelerator error!\n");
  }
  HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (unsigned char*)string, len);

  HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, (uint8_t*)CTRL_REG2, sizeof(CTRL_REG2));
  HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, (uint8_t*)CTRL_REG4, sizeof(CTRL_REG4));

  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;          //or __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(&htim2, TIM_IT_UPDATE); or HAL_Delay(500);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
#if VERSION == 3
      while (!timer_elapsed){/*do nothing*/}

      for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
          dma_complete = false;
          HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA(&hi2c1, ACCEL_ADD, regs[i], I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)(acc+i), 1);

          while (!dma_complete){/*do nothing*/}
      }

      len = snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "X: %+.3fg   Y: %+.3fg   Z: %+.3fg (Tot:%+.3fg | %+.3fm/s²)\n",
              acc[0] / 256.0 * 4.0,
              acc[1] / 256.0 * 4.0,
              acc[2] / 256.0 * 4.0,
              sqrt(pow(acc[0],2)+pow(acc[1],2)+pow(acc[2],2))/64.0,
              sqrt(pow(acc[0],2)+pow(acc[1],2)+pow(acc[2],2))/64.0 * 9.80665);
      HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, (unsigned char*)string, len);

      timer_elapsed = false;
#endif
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


HAL_I2C_Mem_Read_DMA() returns immediately, before it has actually read anything. The reading happens "in the background" while your code continues running. So you'd need to poll for completion before starting a new DMA. (This is why you get HAL_BUSY for the other two reads.) But this is all running in an ISR, and waiting in an ISR for completion is a really bad idea. You probably need to re-think your design.

Also reading one byte using DMA makes no sense at all

@0___________ you're suggesting not to use DMA? Idk why but they said to use I2C with DMA, maybe just to give us the opportunity of solving this specific problem of "synchronization", but I can write in the final report if something is not ok
As they said to us, DMA is usefull because the microprocessor then would be more free and use this when possible, ig that you're saying that waiting for a single byte is not worth the complication of using DMA. Am I right?

@pmacfarlane You're saying that I should use something like HAL_Delay() or GetTick to wait some time in the ISR? Because I tried both things and, idk why, my board completly stopped working with SDA channel low
Now I tried to fix this issue but in a very dirty way imho, but I'm editing the question

@Rob99 who is they?

In your "update 2" you are once again calling HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA() several times in a row without waiting for the DMA to complete. Check the return values from all HAL functions, and you will find some of them are returning HAL_BUSY. Don't use the "DMA" versions in those cases, use the regular polling ones that don't return until the transfer has completed.

A few points:

DMA is normally used if you want some transaction to take place while the CPU continues to run and do other processing. If your code starts a DMA transaction then basically just waits until it is complete, you're not really gaining much benefit.
Interrupt Service Routines (ISRs) such as your two callbacks should ideally do the bare minimum required, and should do it as quickly as possible. If an Operating System is used, they might give a semaphore, or add something to a message queue. With no OS, typically they might just set a flag. All "heavy" processing would take place in your main (non-ISR) code.
When running in an ISR, lower priority interrupts are blocked. So if your system tick interrupt is lower priority than your timer elapsed callback interrupt, functions like HAL_Delay() will not work in the timer interrupt, because the sysTick is not incrementing.

With those points in mind, you could have a design something like this. (Untested, incomplete, but hopefully shows the intent.)
#include <stdbool.h>

static volatile bool timer_elapsed = false;
static volatile bool dma_complete = false;

void main(void)
{
    // Configure all peripherals etc.
    
    
    for (;;)
    {
        // Wait for timer to elapse
        while (!timer_elapsed)
        {
            // You could be doing other things while you wait...
        }
        
        // Read the three registers
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            static const uint8_t regs[] = {OUT_X_ADD, OUT_Y_ADD, OUT_Z_ADD};
            
            dma_complete = false;
            do_i2c_dma(regs[i]); // Call the HAL DMA function

            // Wait for DMA to complete
            while (!dma_complete)
            {
                // You could be doing things here too...
            }
        }
        
        print_results(); // To be implemented
        
        timer_elapsed = false;
    }
}

void HAL_I2C_MemRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)
{
    dma_complete = true;
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
    timer_elapsed = true;
}

The flags are volatile because they are modified in the ISRs, otherwise the main code might assume they never change.

Thanks for this very usefull informations! I didn't know that ISRs we can have so many problems. So it's better with this "flag approach" with both no OS and OS cases? Because I thought that continuing checking for a flag would be less efficient than using ISRs that are called only when needed. I see that volatile is needed to "avoid" compiler optimizations and force it to actually look at the variable, why static tho? In this case, I have just one c file where I write code

static is just good style, if the variable doesn't need to be accessed from another source file. It prevents namespace clutter. It will work equally well without it though. My approach is just one way to do it. Your "updated" code also looks ok to me, but I don't like doing so much work (e.g. the sprintf()) etc in an ISR. But if this is all your code does, it might be ok.

You could even do a hybrid approach, where all the DMA gets driven directly from the ISRs (like in your updated example), then when you have all 3, set a flag that your main code checks. Then the main code can do the sprintf() and the UART transmit. There are lots of options.

Yeah I don't have other code, just the init part for the LIS2DE before the while loop
I add only that, before the HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT I had to put __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT on TIM_IT_UPDATE, or HAL_Delay(500) because otherwise code will stuck in the while(!dma_complete) loop
I found this solution on another question and on reddit too, but no one knows why; by any chance do you know why it happens all the time? Because it would be normal if I tried to reset the board or upload a new firmware when the register exactly when it was set to 1, but it does this every time :/

Not really sure, I'd need to see the code in question. Maybe you should ask a new question showing that code.

I posted my main too, the other code is generated from IDE and I added only the two callbacks that you said
I saw that it's a common issue for the timer, but only in specific cases can be a real problem
I thought because maybe LIS2DE hasn't time to setup correctly everything, but reading the datasheet it seems very fast

If you're still having trouble, post a NEW question with your latest code, and ask a question about it. You can't just keep iterating versions of your code here in response to discussions in comments. I won't be commenting further on this question.


Reading one byte using DMA makes no sense
You need to start the second and third transmission from the callback.



Can you tell me why it's useless? Unfortunately they told us to use it, I'm guessing it's because it's not an heavy load for the microprocessor to handle and it doesn't block it for a long time, am I right?
I've updated the callback but it seems dirty to me :/


@Rob99 1 byte will not block for a long time. No benefit considering the complication. It makes sense if you transfer more.
